# Model caching process leaves files in /tmp

Tags: gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The Gazebo model caching process leaves the files

```
/tmp/gz_model.tar
/tmp/gz_model.tar.gz
```

in /tmp. This blocks subsequent users from downloading more models automatically from your library. The files are write protected so administrative priveleges are needed to get rid of them.
It would be nice if the model download process deleted these files.

Thanks,
Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2312/model-caching-process-leaves-files-in-/tmp/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2013-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Reported here: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/631/using-tmp-gz_modeltargz-is-not-friendly

---

Originally posted by [ThomasK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16/thomask/) with karma: 508 on 2013-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) on 2013-04-11**:
Fixed in https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/437